# If the POST method is not idempotent and is not a safe method, why does the CORS / fetch spec have it listed as a "Safe" method?

Tags: http, post, cors, fetch, idempotent

MDN specifies a "Safe" method as one that does not alter the state of the server. And also defines a method to be "idempotent" if subsequent requests (after the initial one) do not change the outcome. Using that information, we can say that the `POST` method is not safe, and that it is not idempotent right?

So, using that information, why does the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#functional_overview) / [Fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-method) spec have `POST` listed as a Safe Method? That is what confuses me.

I understand the `POST` method can be made idempotent if the server implements such [functionality](https://medium.com/@saurav200892/how-to-achieve-idempotency-in-post-method-d88d7b08fcdd), but none the less, wouldn't the `POST` method still be considered an "unsafe" method? why are they condering it to be a "safe-listed" method along with `GET, HEAD` methods?

I tried searching about the issue but could find a solid explanation, thanks in advance.

Comment: The Fetch spec at https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-method doesn’t list `POST` as a “Safe Method” — instead it lists is as a “CORS-safelisted method”. And “CORS-safelisted” in the context of CORS and “safe” in the broader context of HTTP don’t mean the same thing at all. All that “CORS-safelisted method” means in the context of CORS is, it’s not a method that will always trigger a CORS preflight. It has nothing to do with idempotency.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I think it's _safe_ to say you can turn your comment into an answer :)